# pop up dialog box on the same screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement as below in the flutter.

Please do comply.

[image]

Comment: This is not how Stack Overflow works. If you need to get this done, hire a professional developer. If you want help to do it yourself, show us your best effort and explain where you are stuck so we can give you help reaching your goal.

Comment: In a way, you are asking me to pay you. I am here just trying to get an idea or just a hint. I am not asking someone or somebody to fully code for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PopupMenuButton`:

```
PopupMenuButton(
  onSelected: () { setState(() { _selection = result; }); },
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<>>[
    const PopupMenuItem<>(
      value: value,
      child: Text('help and feedback'),
    ),
    const PopupMenuItem<>(
      value: value,
      child: Text('history controls'),
    ),
    const PopupMenuItem<>(
      value: value,
      child: Text('watch on tv'),
    ),
  ],
)
```

here is the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html).

Comment: Sounds good to me as what I expected. You saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [DropdownButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html). Here's how to make one,

```
return DropdownButton<String>(
  value: dropdownValue,
  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
  iconSize: 24,
  elevation: 16,
  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
  underline: Container(
    height: 2,
    color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
  ),
  onChanged: (String? newValue) {
    setState(() {
      dropdownValue = newValue!;
    });
  },
  items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four'].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: value,
      child: Text(value),
    );
  }).toList(),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution ! Really appreciated your fast response.